# When/why do you use kill %%?

Tags: linux, bash, kill

I've seen people use `kill %%` rather than `kill %`. As far as I can tell, they both do the same. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the documentation:

> There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell.  The
>   character % introduces a job specification (jobspec).   Job  number  n
>   may  be
>          referred to as %n.  A job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears
>   in its command
>          line.  For example, %ce refers to a stopped ce job.  If a prefix matches more than one job, bash reports an error.  Using %?ce, 
>   on  the  other
>          hand,  refers to any job containing the string ce in its command line.  If the substring matches more than one job, bash
>   reports an error.  **The
>          symbols %%** and %+ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground  or 
>   started  in
>          the  background.  The previous job may be referenced using %-.  If there is only a single job, %+ and %- can both be used to refer to
>   that job.
>          In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous
>   job with a -.
>          **A single %** (with no accompanying job specification) also refers to the current job.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: So essentially, both %% and % refer to the current (most recent) job. Good to know that %% is also valid - I suspected the second % was not necessary.